# Getting Resolution-Aware Images from Backend URL

Tags: flutter

Flutter offers resolution-aware asset images. However, I am curious how others implemented retrieving resolution-aware images from their backend URL that they have influence over.

My plan is to preprocess the highest resolution original image into lower resolution versions with respective suffixes for: 0.75x (ldpi), 1.00x (mdpi), 1.50x (hdpi), 2.00x (xdpi), 3.00x (xxdpi), and 4.00x (xxxdpi). Then use devicePixelRatio to determine the appropriate suffix to append to the image filename.